# Why my question was put on hold

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

[My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2822362/1) was about derivatives, and I thought it was a good question.

But then, Moderators put my question [on hold] saying that it was off-topic. Now, I am wondering why it was an off-topic post. Can you explain?

Comment: I see that you edit your post (to add context) around 33 mins ago and three minutes later asks this meta question. I mean, it takes time for people to review your edit and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand your question. It said this on the page:

> "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." –

Apparently you understood this and followed up on it, which is good. Now you have to wait if the post gets reopened. If you want to know why it did not yet get reopened, then you should ask about this. Why it was put "on hold" in the first place is pretty well-documented though.

Comment: Can you define what do you meant by missing context? And, what in my question can I improve?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question. I  do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Another problem with your question is that it asks two questions in one post this is generally not appreciated, which might be a reason why it did not get reponed despite you adding some context.

Comment: Reason for asking two questions: This morning, I had only few hours before my Internal test and I got these two questions